# Have Outlook 2010 Only Sync RSS Feeds Once a Day

Tags: rss, microsoft-outlook-2010

I keep spending too much time looking at my RSS feeds and only want it to update once a day. Is it possible to put this setting in place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Click on File - Options - Advanced
- Scroll down to the "Send and receive" section and click on Send/Receive button
- Select All Accounts and Click on Edit
- Select RSS under accounts and uncheck box "Include RSS Feeds in this Send/Receive group" and click ok
- Click New and type a Group Name and click OK
- Select RSS under accounts and check box "Include RSS Feeds in this Send/Receive group" and click ok
- Select newly created group and right below check box "Schedule an automatic send/receive every" and input minutes.  If you want every 24 hours its 1440 minutes.